# pcl::io::loadPCDFile from objective-c ends in EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: c++, objective-c, std, point-cloud-library

I am trying to use pcl from an objective-c application. I have the following bit of code:

```
int i;
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
i = pcl::io::loadPCDFile("test.pcd", *cloud);
```

I am creating a very simple Cocoa application with a button. When the button is pressed, a procedure containing only the above code is called. The file containing the code above is an objective-c++ file.

The problem is, that the call to pcl::io::loadPCDFile ends in an EXC_BAD_ACCESS. The stack_trace is

```
#0  0x00007fff8ecb60ef in std::string::compare(char const*) const ()
#1  0x000000010007e42d in bool std::operator==<char, std::char_traits<char>,     std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, char const*) at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/basic_string.h:2177
#2  0x00000001007bedea in pcl::PCDReader::readHeader(std::string const&, pcl::PCLPointCloud2&, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1, 0, 4, 1>&, Eigen::Quaternion<float, 0>&, int&, int&, unsigned int&, int) at /Users/jkp/Development/pointclouds/pcl-pcl-1.7.0/io/src/pcd_io.cpp:133
#3  0x00000001007c2a47 in pcl::PCDReader::read(std::string const&, pcl::PCLPointCloud2&, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1, 0, 4, 1>&, Eigen::Quaternion<float, 0>&, int&, int) at /Users/jkp/Development/pointclouds/pcl-pcl-1.7.0/io/src/pcd_io.cpp:675
#4  0x0000000100002e6d in int pcl::PCDReader::read<pcl::PointXYZ>(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>&, int) at /usr/local/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/io/pcd_io.h:208
#5  0x0000000100002213 in int pcl::io::loadPCDFile<pcl::PointXYZ>(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>&) at /usr/local/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/io/pcd_io.h:544
#6  0x00000001000015af in read() at /Users/jkp/Development/pointclouds/load_test/load_test/pcl_routines.cpp:18
```

I have tried moving my code to a .cpp file to keep the pcl-related code in pure c++, but same result.

If I debug the code and step through, I can see that when readHeader is called, the variable file_name seems to be invalid.

If I use the examples from the pcl documentation, they compile and run fine.

Is there a setting or something obvious I have overlooked?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

EDIT:

(Moved my answer to an answer. Yes I'm a noob here. Sorry :) )

Comment: are you able to implement pcl in iOS? i'm try to do same. it would be helpful if you can share your demo project. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out. I had the same problem if I created a C++ prject in XCode. If I used cmake to generate an XCode project and compiled that in XCode, I had no problems. It turns out that my own project had chosen libc++ as C++ Standard Library. If I choose Compile Default instead, the code works.

Leaving this here, in case anyone with the same problem comes by. And added stdlib, since this was a problem with choosing the wrong stdlib.